# User keeps getting locked out

Tags: active-directory, security, user-accounts

An AD user continuously keeps getting locked out for no reason. There are no persistent drive mappings and the user is not logging in anywhere else. In Windows event viewer there are constant logs of the user logging in (event id 4624) and logging out (event id 4634) within a second. While I believe this might be causing the problem I don't understand why this would happen. This happens several times a day.

```
Log Name:      Security
Source:        Microsoft-Windows-Security-Auditing
Date:          6/26/2017 10:35:37 AM
Event ID:      4740
Task Category: User Account Management
Level:         Information
Keywords:      Audit Success
User:          N/A
Computer:      DC.domain.com
Description:
A user account was locked out.

Subject:
    Security ID:        SYSTEM
    Account Name:       DC$
    Account Domain:     domain
    Logon ID:       0x3E7

Account That Was Locked Out:
    Security ID:        domain\user
    Account Name:       user

Additional Information:
    Caller Computer Name:   
Event Xml:
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
  <System>
    <Provider Name="Microsoft-Windows-Security-Auditing" Guid="{54849625-5478-4994-A5BA-3E3B0328C30D}" />
    <EventID>4740</EventID>
    <Version>0</Version>
    <Level>0</Level>
    <Task>13824</Task>
    <Opcode>0</Opcode>
    <Keywords>0x8020000000000000</Keywords>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2017-06-26T14:35:37.402913000Z" />
    <EventRecordID>186521580</EventRecordID>
    <Correlation />
    <Execution ProcessID="820" ThreadID="1708" />
    <Channel>Security</Channel>
    <Computer>DC.domain.com</Computer>
    <Security />
  </System>
  <EventData>
    <Data Name="TargetUserName">user</Data>
    <Data Name="TargetDomainName">
    </Data>
    <Data Name="TargetSid">S-1-5-21-2106544897-1787049590-12547700-6366</Data>
    <Data Name="SubjectUserSid">S-1-5-18</Data>
    <Data Name="SubjectUserName">R-DC$</Data>
    <Data Name="SubjectDomainName">domain</Data>
    <Data Name="SubjectLogonId">0x3e7</Data>
  </EventData>
</Event>
```

Comment: Show us the full text/details of the event. There is valuable information that can help you narrow down the cause, such as Logon Type, Source Network Address, etc.

Comment: `An AD user continuously keeps getting locked out for no reason.` That's patently untrue.  They're getting locked out because something, from some device, is authenticating against AD with the wrong credentials, period.  On that note, I once had some HR twit with this problem because she put a .bat file in her startup folder to map her home printer on her work desktop.  It didn't work, but it sure locked her out every 90 seconds.

Answer (score 2):

I would enable logging for failed attempts as a diagnostic, if you have not already. Then you can see how many times the account is being hit. The failed attempts should have a computer name tied to them, and that would tell you where things are coming from for sure. If the account is getting locked out very quickly, you may have a malicious attempt to break into an account.

Comment: We have this repeatedly: a user changes his passord, but does not change it in the ActiveSync settings in his phone. After only a few minutes, the account gets locked out.

Comment: Yes, we see this all the time as well. We actually have some powershell scripts that will email an exchange group upon a lockout event on the DC. It dumps the event to the email body text, so we can see the "Source" of the lockout. If it is the mail server, that narrows it down quite a bit.

Answer (score 1):

Have you insured all saved credentials have been removed under Credential Manager in the Control Panel? Had this happen once and it turned out to be old credentials that were saved. You will have to do this on all servers/ computers they log into.

Comment: I've tried getting rid of old credentials. It solves the problem for about a week then it keeps happening again.

Comment: Blow away the Profile (back it up obviously) on the PC and create a new one if you only have 1 PC or get the user to log into another PC and see if the same thing happens.

My hunch is if it is going away after deleting old saved credentials something is saving old credentials again and causing problems. Could be a corrupt profile.